# In Swift 3 - I am trying to change the color of a button for a second after clicking it, so the user will get an indication if was right or wrong

Tags: swift, uibutton

In Swift 3 - I am trying to change the color of the button for a second after clicking it, so the user will get an indication if was right or wrong. It seems like I need to force update the display, but I am not sure how.

```
@IBAction func answer1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.tag == rightAnswerPlacement) {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        gmaeScore += 1
    } else {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        gmaeScore -= 1
    }
    sleep(1)
    score.text = "Score: \(gmaeScore)"
    newQuestion()
}

func newQuestion() {
    var firstResult: Int, secondResult: Int, thirdResult: Int, finalResult:Int
    (firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult, finalResult) = generateQuestion()

    timeCount = 0

    firstAnswer.text = String(firstResult)
    secondAnswer.text = String(secondResult)
    thirdAnswer.text = String(thirdResult)

    rightAnswerPlacement = generateNumber(range: 4, positive: true)

    var button:UIButton = UIButton()

    var alternativeAnswer = 0

    //IUterate over the buttons

    var allAnswers = Set<Int>()
    allAnswers.insert(finalResult)

    for i in 1...4 {
        //Converting each of the buuton tags into a button
        button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        if (i == Int(rightAnswerPlacement)){
            button.setTitle(String(finalResult), for: .normal)
        } else {
            var myRange = finalResult * 2
            if (myRange < 0) {
                myRange *= -1
            }
            alternativeAnswer =  generateNumber(range: myRange)
            while allAnswers.contains(alternativeAnswer) {
                alternativeAnswer =  generateNumber(range: myRange)
            }
            allAnswers.insert(alternativeAnswer)
            button.setTitle(String(alternativeAnswer), for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your code as text not as an image.

Comment: @Nir.Hayun please [edit] the question - the comments are not for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBAction func answer1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.tag == rightAnswerPlacement) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        },completion: { _ in
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green //change it back to original color
        })

        gmaeScore += 1
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            sender.backgroundColor = .red
        },completion: { _ in
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green //change it back to original color
        })
        gmaeScore -= 1
    }
    sleep(1)
    score.text = "Score: \(gmaeScore)"
    newQuestion()
}
```

The completion block will execute after your duration :)

Comment: It works! First of all thank you! Now it change its color only after the question changes. I want it to change the color before.

Comment: Well you could store that color in a variable and use that later on with above code :)

Comment: @J.Doe Any idea what am I doing wrong here? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499230

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@IBAction func answer1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            sender.backgroundColor = .green
            sender.backgroundColor = .red
        }
}
```